# Touch movement will not animate

Tags: actionscript-3

Ok, so I'm in the process of developing a game in Adobe Flash (air) it will be a mobile game.I asked this question a while ago, but animation doesn't work so know I'm back.Anyway, the problem I was having was that there was no continuous movement when I held down a button, so I had to constantly keep pressing the button to move.the person told me to use ticks, so it's how I built the movement engine, all around ticks.When I go to add my animation, it goes once and just stops (the animation) here is my code:

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mouseDown);

function mouseDown(e:Event):void {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUp); //listen for mouse up on the stage, in case the finger/mouse moved off of the button accidentally when they release.
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tick); //while the mouse is down, run the tick function once every frame as per the project frame, this is where I add the players animation.
}

function mouseUp(e:Event):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tick);  //stop running the tick function every frame now that the mouse is up
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,mouseUp); //remove the listener for mouse up
}

function tick(e:Event):void {
    //do your movement
}
```

What I'm saying is, is there anyway to get around the problem? How can I animate with the tick!

Comment: You're code no problem. tick handler work fine. exactly what have you problem? Can you give me a link to your source?

Comment: My problem is that I have an animation moving frame, on the mouse down handler I insert the gotoandplay and at the end of the animation it loops, my problem is it only plays once and doesn't loop.

Comment: ok, give me a you're source link. Willing'll help. Exactly what I can not post a definite answer without seeing the code.

Comment: The code I used is there.

Comment: I tried to your code run, do not have a problem. tick handler works very fine. You how the structure of the object, such as the timeline of the Movieclip inside information I need. Full source required.

Comment: try to put "stop()" at the last frame of your moving animation, it will stop your animation, after play once.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I find the code perfectly fine. Since, I don't have access to entire code and timeline, I have the below guess about the problem:

Since, you want to start animation only on mouse down, then you must be having a stop() action in the first frame of your animation. (Please correct me if this isn't the case). The last frame of your animation must be having gotoAndPlay(x) action again for looping.

Based on above assumption, when your animation loops, it again reaches a frame which has stop() action already defined.